# Catch SIGINT and call a method in an object

Tags: python, methods, call, sigint

I know how to capture SIGINT / SIGTERM signal in Python, but all examples I found are very primitive. I need to call a specified method in an object when SIGINT or SIGTERM occurs, is there any way how to implement this?

```
def sigint_handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Stop pressing the CTRL+C!'

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)

class MyObject:
    def terminate (self):
        do_something()
```

When I try to add another argument to `sigint_handler`, I get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you added the part

> When I try to add another argument to sigint_handler, I get an error.

to your Question, but i'll first cover that:

use a `wrapper` or `partial` (which is a wrapper-factory) like so:

```
>>> def my_wrapped_sigint_handler(my_argument):
...   def signal_handler(signum, frame): # the actual sigint handler
...      print(my_argument) # or do something useful
...   return signal_handler
... 
>>> signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, my_wrapped_sigint_handler('FOO'))
```

or using partial:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def sigint_handler(signum, frame, my_argument):
...    print(my_argument) # or do something useful
... 
>>> signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, partial(sigint_handler, my_argument="foobar"))
```

to adress your original question using the technique above:

```
>>> class MyObject:
...     def terminate (self):
...         do_something()
... 
>>> def sigint_handler(signum, frame, obj):
...   obj.terminate()
... 
>>> signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, partial(sigint_handler, obj=MyObject()))
```

will call `MyObject`'s instance's `.terminate()` on `^C`.

Comment: Thanks, tried version with partial, works like a charm.